# How to add adjectives to "enthusiast"

Tags: phrase-usage

For description of a resume I wrote:

> Diligent,  **research enthusiast** and skillful programmer, with  over 20 years experience in teaching, research and software development  in the areas of Natural Language Processing, Information Systems, Web  applications.

I would like to know if "research enthusiast" is a correct combination or I should phrase it something else.

Answer (score 2):

**"Research enthusiast"** is *someone who is enthusiastic about research*. Similarly, a *football enthusiast* is someone who is very interested in football, or spends a lot of time playing it. Therefore, your phrase *"research enthusiast"* is a correct combination. It can be modified by an adjective like *'diligent'*; but the comma should be omitted after the adjective : *"Diligent research enthusiast and..."*